# How to detect phoenix application started from `mix phx.server`?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I have some workers (children) in `Application.start`. They shouldn't be started if phoenix app running from task other than `mix phx.server` (for example with `mix ecto.reset`).
So, how to know in `Application.start` that it is `mix phx.server` running the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Phoenix.Endpoint.server?(otp_app, endpoint)` to check if an endpoint is running its server under the given app. Here are the docs: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html#server?/2

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented way to check if the application was started as a task, e. g. because the application does not have a `mix` dependency on production.

Typically, that sort of fine tuning is resolved by using `:included_applications` in project config and loading them manually if needed from [`Application.start/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#start/2) when required with [`Application.ensure_started/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#ensure_started/2). For the condition to check one might use an environment variable (optionally via the task alias):

```
LOAD_INCLUDED=app1,app2,app3 mix ecto.reset
```

and somewhere in `Application.start/2`:

```
"LOAD_INCLUDED"
|> System.get_env()
|> Enum.split(",")
|> Enum.map(&String.to_atom/1)
|> Application.ensure_started()
```

---

If these workers are your own workers, it’s even easier: just call `Kernel.++/2` with a list of conditional workers based on the environment variable.

*Sidenote:* in production, the application is started as an OTP release, without `mix` included and therefore an explicit check for `mix phx.server` makes zero sense.